# Value of improper integral as the interval of integration goes to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Let $f: (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and suppose that the improper integral $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ converges -- i.e. the limit $\lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0}\int_\epsilon^1 f(x)dx$ exists. Is it true that

$$\lim_{\eta \searrow 0}\int_0^\eta f(x)dx = 0.$$

The answer seems clear to me, *if* the function $f$ could be continuously extended the closed interval $[0,1]$, since then $f$ is bounded by compactnes of $[0,1]$ and the length of the interval we are integrating over goes to $0$. But if $f$ cannot be extended continuously to $[0,1]$, I suspect the result still to be true, only I don't have a resonable argument for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be defined by $F(\epsilon)=\int_\epsilon^1f$ if $0<\epsilon\le1,$ and $F(0)=\lim_{0^+}F.$

By definition, $\int_0^\eta f=F(0)-F(\eta)$ hence $\lim_{\eta\to0^+}\int_0^\eta f=0.$